# tomcat server does not start in eclipse

Tags: tomcat7, eclipse-neon

Whenever i try to run my servlet program on the server, it shows this error:

> Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

I tried changing the port numbers but still there is issue with the port number. What should I do?

Comment: To get open ports follow the below steps,

open cmd.exe,
execute cmd "netstat -ano",
Pick any one which you find is free

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue,

1. Open tomcat bin
2. Execute shutdown batch file for windows
3. Refresh eclipse and it will solve the problem

Hope this answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works, end all services which are active and using that port. Usualy port number 8080.
Also, you can do this:

right click proj-> properties-> Targeted Runtimes -> *tick tomcat version on your pc or create new one*